# Python: avoid sublists pointing to the same element

Tags: python, list, reference

In Python, I want a `list` containing a given number of sublists of the form `[0,0]`. For instance:

```
>>> myLen = 2
>>> myList = [[0,0]] * myLen
>>> myList
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

It turns out that each sublist always points to the same element, so modifying one automatically modifies the other.

```
>>> myList[0][0] = 2
>>> myList
[[2, 0], [2, 0]]
```

Why is that? How do I avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
myList = [[0,0] for _ in range(myLen)]
```

to create separate sublists.

When you multiply a list, the inner list is not copied, only the *reference to the sublist* is copied. You essentially do this:

```
myList = [[0,0]]
for _ in range(myLen - 1):
    myList.append(myList[0])
```

A list comprehension, on the other hand, executes the *expression* that creates the sublist for each loop iteration, so on each run-through a completely new list is created:

```
myList = []
for _ in range(myLen):
    myList.append([0,0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use numpy:

```
import numpy
matrix = numpy.zeros(myLen, 2)
```

Source: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html